# vue js transition between two divs , each div with a seperate button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

so i have two buttons one for displaying the login div and one for displaying the signup div i want to make it that when i click on the login button it shows the login div and the same for the sign up
i'm using vue with cdn as the following:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

**this was my try to do it**:
in my js file

```
 new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true,
  }
})
```

in my html file

```
<div id="demo">
    <div>
        <button v-on:click="show"> Signin </button>
        <button v-on:click="else">Signup</button>
    </div>
    <transition name="fade">
    <div v-if="show" >
        <h2> Signin </h2>
    <p> this is the signin page </p>

</div>
<div v-else>
    <h2> Signup </h2>
<p> this is the signup page </p>
</div>
</transition>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Vue what the `show` variable needs to become when it's clicked.

So add the following to your at click events

```html
 <button v-on:click="show = true"> Signin </button>
 <button v-on:click="show = false">Signup</button>
```